# how can I load the leaflet map in advance?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, preload

When the application starts, it is kinda slow to load the map at run time.

Is there a way to save the leaflet map in local or improve the loading speed in browser?

Answer (score 3):

What is a leaflet map for you ? Remember Leaflet itself loads the content from a tile provider.
If you don't want to request the tile map over the internet, you may download one locally and somehow link leaflet and your own installation.

OpenStreetMap allow users to download their own tile provider.
[How to install Nominatim locally](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation)

If you want to store your leaflet objects (like markers, paths, etc.) the localStorage Javascript's variable can help you.